# Audio running in background after changing the activity or minimizing the app

Tags: android

Audio is running in the background when I change the video activity or minimizing the android app.I don't want that background audio. This bug is reproducing sometimes, sometimes it works perfectly fine. I have implemented mPlayer.stop() method in onPause and onStop method. Can somebody help me out on this?

Comment: Try: getMediaController().getTransportControls().stop();

Comment: If that helps I will reply by answer and you will vote it)

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void onPause() {
        mediaplayer.stop();
        mediaplayer.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

try this one.if it's helpful upvote this